# About UIScroll View?

Tags: ios

I am designing my UI which basically has three parts

```
View 
  --Navigation Items
  --Contents
  --Tab View Items
```

I want my contents to be scrollable.

Is it possible to use

```
ScrollView
  --Navigation Items
  --Contents
  --Tab View Items
```

Or I have to use

```
View
  --Navigation Items
  --ScrollView
    --Contents
  --Tab View Items
```

Comment: There are no laws, but the second one is much more usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the second one, and it should be

```
    --ViewController
      --Navigation Items
      --View
        --ScrollView
          --Contents
      --Tab View Items
```

because navigationItem is a property of UIViewController, not a property of UIView.